# Selenium C# - Capture value of field

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I need to capture the value of the status field with xpath `.//*[@id='status-val']/span` and check that it equals the desired value (ie TODO in this case). How can I retrieve the value of a field in which I know the xpath of using selenium, `C#` and `NUnit`? See below for a screenshot of the field and firebug

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 1):

The "TODO" is text in this case, you can get it using `Text` member

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//*[@id='status-val']/span"));
string text = element.Text;
```

You can also try the `GetAttribute` method

```
string text = element.GetAttribute("value");
```